# Passing string with spaces to bash script and using within string concatenation

Tags: bash

I have an argument to a bash script which could be a string with spaces. How can I use this within a string concatenation such as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"text":"'$1'"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/<rest of URL secret!>
```

From cmd line if I do:

```
$./myscript.sh oneword
```

It works perfectly fine. But if I pass a string with spaces:

```
$./myscript.sh "two words"

curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 5
invalid_payload%
```

I have tried all sorts of quoting to concatenate it correctly, but to no avail. Thanks

Comment: Don't generate JSON by hand, unless (maybe) you already know that `$1` is a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote `$1` as well in your JSON payload:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"text":"'"$1"'"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/<rest of URL secret!>
```

Comment: Even this may fail if `$1` can't safely be merged (it might contain a double quote itself).

Comment: If double quotes can also be passed in `$1` then OP may use: `"${1//\"/\\\"}"`

Comment: Letting something like `jq` construct the JSON is far safer. `"$(jq -n --arg x "$1" '{text: $x}')"`.